# Convert using statement from c# to python

Tags: python

Help needed convert c# code to python. Need help converting using statement from c# to python. For the following example Using statement in the function public Dictionary

```c#
public class Class1
{
    public static string GetUrlStartingAtPath(string url)
    {
        Regex pathEx = new Regex(@"(?in)^https?:\/{0,3}[0-9.\-A-Za-z]+(:\d+)?(?<content>.+)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        // parse out the path
        return pathEx.Match(url).Groups[1].ToString();
    }
    public static long GetUnixEpochTime()
    {
        // UNIX epoch
        var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var milliseconds = (long)(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - epoch).TotalMilliseconds;
        return milliseconds;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetCodes(string url)
    {
        const string SBO_KEY_1 = "1";
        const string SBO_KEY_TEXT_1 = "PQ/OZW8SZCU/wUwm2u+Os6oyAmiFfif6QGVAhCLUahh36ui7BJfwymytCgULDZ6G111ud6SuySii544A6Uw+Tw==";
        Dictionary<string, byte[]> sboKeys = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
        var b64 = Convert.FromBase64String(SBO_KEY_TEXT_1);
        sboKeys.Add(SBO_KEY_1, Convert.FromBase64String(SBO_KEY_TEXT_1));
        string scheme = "1";
        long unixEpochTime = GetUnixEpochTime();
        var sboKey = sboKeys[scheme];

        // store the headers we'll return
        var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        // parse out the path
        string urlFromPath = GetUrlStartingAtPath(Uri.UnescapeDataString(url));

        // create base message
        var baseMessage = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}:{1}", unixEpochTime, urlFromPath);

        // create signable message
        var signable = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseMessage);

        // create crypto class
        using (var hmacsha1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(sboKey))
        {
            // create hash
            var hash = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(signable);
            // add headers
            headers.Add("SNL-Request-Time", unixEpochTime.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
            headers.Add("SNL-Request-Client", String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}:{1}", scheme, Convert.ToBase64String(hash)));
        }

        // done
        return headers;
    }


    public void main()
    {
        string url = "http://localhost/SNL.Services.Data.Api.Service/v2/Internal/General/SecurityIndexs?$select=KeyIndex,IndexShortNameDisplay&$expand=PricingMRIndexs($select=IndexPriceChange,IndexPriceChangeActual,IndexValue,PricingAsOf),SecurityIndexValues($select=IndexValue,PricingAsOf;$filter=PricingAsOf+gt+2019-01-12;$expand=IndexValueChanges($select=IndexPriceChange,IndexPriceChangeActual;$filter=KeyPricePeriod+eq+1);$orderby=PricingAsOf)&$filter=KeyIndex+eq+1+or+KeyIndex+eq+2+or+KeyIndex+eq+4+or+KeyIndex+eq+196+or+KeyIndex+eq+339&$orderby=KeyIndex&cache=3600";
        var Codes = GetCodes(url);
        foreach (var k in Codes.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(k + " = " + Codes[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `using` statement in C# is like the `import` statement in Python. But I don't think you'll find a single line conversion from `using System`. You'll just have to add `import` statements as you need them. Like `import re` for regex.

Comment: It was a different "using statement". Apologies for misunderstanding

Comment: In that case, I think it would be more like the `with` statement in Python. [What is the python "with" statement designed for?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3012488)

Comment: Here's a question about HMACSHA1 and none of the answers use `with` so it may not be needed in your code: [Implementation HMAC-SHA1 in python](//stackoverflow.com/q/8338661)